# Can complex selectors be used inside the `:where()` or `:is()` pseudo class functions?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am using JS's `querySelectorAll()` to get some elements.  The following selector works as I want: `main > div, main > section, main > ul > li`.

I would like to remove the `main >`  redundancy part of that.  The following works for me:  `main > :where(div, section), main > ul > li`.

But, I cannot figure out how to get the `ul > li` complex selector portion to work *inside* there `:where()` function.  It is just ignored.  The `div` and `section` are picked up, just like a *forgiving-selector-list* should.

From what I can see, `div, section, ul > li` is a valid selector list.

However, in my research, I have only seen uses of `:where()` or `:is()` with simple selectors, maybe compound.

What am I missing?

If it matters, I am using Firefox 117.0.1

---

#### This snippet works using separate selectors:

```css
main > div,
main > section,
main > ul > li {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>

   <div>Div</div>
   
   <section>Section</section>
   
   <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
   </ul>

</main>
```

---

#### This snippet works using `:where()` for `div, section`:

```css
main > :where(div, section),
main > ul > li {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>

   <div>Div</div>
   
   <section>Section</section>
   
   <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
   </ul>

</main>
```

---

#### This snippet *doesn't work* using `:where()` for `div, section` and `ul > li`:

```css
main > :where(div, section, ul > li) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>

   <div>Div</div>
   
   <section>Section</section>
   
   <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
   </ul>

</main>
```

Comment: `ul > li` isn't a compound-selector (a [compound-selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_selectors/Selectors_and_combinators#compound-selector) is just when you use a type-selector with a class and/or id selector, so `div#foo.bar` is a compound-selector, while using _any_ combinators (like `>` (child) or ` ` (descendent)) makes it a complex-selector. Just FYI.

Comment: Doh!  Thought one, wrote the other.

Comment: I added interactive snippets demonstrating the issue to your post - HTH.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to select `li`? If it's just for things like `color:` then you can use `:where(div, section, ul)` and the `li` will inherit it from the `ul`.

Comment: This is for a userscript where I am adding hotkey navigation to a website.  On some pages, the items I want to navigate are large items wrapped by `li`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't to-do with using a [complex-selector](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#complex) with `:where()` and `:is()` - or anything to do with them using a [*forgiving-selector-list*](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#typedef-forgiving-selector-list); the problem is that `main > :where(ul > li)` **is not satisfiable**.

The current (draft) specification for CSS Selectors Level 4, [defines `:where()` as being identical to `:is()` but with a specificity of zero](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#where-pseudo), so let's take a look at `:is()` instead:

https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#matches

> the [`:is()`] pseudo-class matches any element that matches any of the selectors in the list.

...therefore, `main > :where(ul > li)` matches elements that simultaneously satisfy:

- Is an immediate child of `main`
- Is an `li` that is **also** an immediate child of `ul`
- But an element cannot be an immediate child of two different parent elements.
- Therefore the selector cannot be satisfied.

---

> I would like to remove the `main >`  redundancy part of that. The following works for me:
>
> ```css
> main > :where(div, section),
> main > ul > li
> ```

The problem here is that *you think that's what you ought to do*. I don't see any "redundancy" in your selectors. While this might superficially look like a violation of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), in my opinion it is not; or summarized as: **you cannot simplify your selector any further**.

---

The snippet below demonstrates that you **can** use a complex-selector inside `:where()` or `:is()`, provided the selector is still satisfiable, in this case, by using the descendant combinator   (a space) instead of the child combinator `>`, like so:

```
main :where(ul > li, div)
```

This works because an element `e` that matches `ul > li` can *also* match `main e` (but not `main > e`). But this selector *also* matches other `ul > li` descendants of `main`, such as *List item 3* below:

```css
ul { color: blue; }

main :where(ul > li, div) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>

   <div>Div (red)</div>
   
   <section>Section (black)</section>
   
   <ul>
    <li>List item 1 (red)</li>
    <li>List item 2 (red)</li>
   </ul>

   <fieldset>
       List in a fieldset
       <ul>
        <li>List item 3 (red)</li>
        <li>List item 4 (red)</li>
       </ul>
   </fieldset>


</main>
```